# Can't change the mutableListOf( ) values

Tags: kotlin

Kindly look at the code,

```
fun main()
{
var y = mutableListOf( "MH", 19, true  )

        y[0] = "value4"     // showing error in this line

        println( y[0] )
}
```

When i try to change the "MH" value. it shows me the following error.

***Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Nothing was expected***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed types. All of them are subclasses of `Any`, but also subtypes of `Comparable<*>`. The compiler picks the lower type when you leave it to be implicitly chosen. In this case, the lower type is `Comparable<*>`, but the star projection prevents you from adding anything to the list.

To prevent the implicit typing, specify it explicitly:

```
var y = mutableListOf<Any>( "MH", 19, true  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to specify the type explicitly

```
val y: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf( "MH", 19, true )
```

**#bnus**

even though **y** is a **val**, its value is mutable since it has been assigned to a mutableList but still can't be reassigned. The same scenario applies to other mutable collections.

for more information see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html